# Redirecting according to the JSON value from the URL "[FLUTTER] "

Tags: json, flutter, dart-html

The URL has a return in JSON format. The data here comes as [{"operation":"0"}] or [{"operation":"1"}]. According to the value here, I will redirect to another site in flutter. I couldn't solve the problem. The code I tried is as follows.

```
Future<List> login() async{
final response = await http.get("https://www.exampleurl.com");

var datauser = response.body;

if(datauser == 0 ){

print(datauser);
print(Text("Giriş Başarılı"),
);
}
else{
print(datauser);
print(Text(“Giriş Başarısız”));
}
}
```

**I get this as the output of this code.**

flutter: ï»¿[{“islem”:0}]
flutter: Text(“Giriş Başarısız”)

Answer (score 0):

You should use jsonDecode to access `operation` value

```
Future<List> login() async{
final response = await http.get("https://www.exampleurl.com");

var datauser = jsonDecode(response.body)[0];

if(datauser['operation'] == 0 ){

print(datauser);
print(Text("Giriş Başarılı"),
);
}
else{
print(datauser);
print(Text(“Giriş Başarısız”));
}
}
```

do not forget to import

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

Comment: [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
<html>
^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1405:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1272:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:937:22)
#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:506:36)
#5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:157:41)

Comment: #6      jsonDecode (dart:convert/json.dart:96:10)
<asynchronous suspension>

Comment: ERROR MESSAGE :((